# Get date from datepicker using dialogfragment

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialog, android-datepicker

I'm using the google example to insert a datepicker inside my app using a dialogfragment
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

But I'm not sure how to get date after set it (not java expert). Dialog and datepicker runs ok and I can log that date is correctely set but, how can i do to get a callback executed on parent activity?

This is my Dialog fragment

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        **Log.w("DatePicker","Date = " + year);**
    }
}
```

...and I call dialog from my activity with...

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

What is the correct way to call a method in my parent activity instead Log.w? I suppose that is something related with passing a callback as parameter or something but most of references I found on internet are about previous versions without dialogfragments

EDIT: not sure if it's important but parent activity is declared as:

```
public class EditSessionActivity extends FragmentActivity {
```

**SOLUTION: thanks to Lecho user this is the way to do it**

DatePickerFragmennt.class

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);
    }

}
```

...and parent activity EditSessionActivity.class...

```
public class EditSessionActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnDateSetListener {
...
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //do some stuff for example write on log and update TextField on activity
        Log.w("DatePicker","Date = " + year);
        ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_date)).setText("Date = " + year);
    }
```

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Constructor fo `DatePickerDialog` takes `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` as second parameter, so maybe you should implement that interface in your parent activity `EditSessionActivity` (not in `DatePickerFragment` ) and change this line:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
```

into this:

```
return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);
```

And then your activity should looks like this:

```
public class EditSessionActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        //use date in your activity
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: that's was usefull, I'll extend my question including your solution.
I'd recommend to every one to read about implementing interfaces. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/usinginterface.html

Comment: Instead of casting to EditSessionActivity, I guess you mean casting to OnDateSetListener.

Comment: Yes, you're right, it will be cast to OnDateSetListener anyway as EditSessionActivity implements OnDateSetListener but your suggestion will make code more clear.

Comment: What do you do if you have two or more date fields which should be filled using DatePickerDialog? Can you discriminate in onDateSet(), for which field the DatePickerDialog was called?

Comment: I that case I usually implement custom DialogFragment that takes some flag which lets me later to discriminate for which field it was shown. I also need custom listener for that. Look at this gist for example implementation https://gist.github.com/lecho/9305505. It is time picker but date picker would be very similar.

Answer (score 25):

I simple override onDateSet in date picker creation in my class that shows a date picker.
See code below:

```
  private OnClickListener onDateClicked() {
    return new OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
             DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
                  salePaymentCustomView.setBtDateText("" + day + "/" + month+1 + "/" + year);
                }
             };
             newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    }
  };
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, This one is easy in case of multiple date fields

Comment: Thanks, it's the simplest solution I've seen so far!

Comment: When I try , I am getting this error - 
Fragments should be static such that they can be re-instantiated by the system, and anonymous classes are not static

Answer (score 14):

The problem can also be solved without moving the `onDateSet` method to the parent activity. You just have to tell the `DatePickerFragment` where to search for the view:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // do some stuff for example write on log and update TextField on activity
        Log.w("DatePicker","Date = " + year);
        ((TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tf_date)).setText("Date = " + year);
    }
}
```

I also changed the target of the cast from `EditText` to `TextView`. This way, you can reuse your implementation for different kinds of views, not only for an `EditText`.

Answer (score 10):

i have one correction to the above answer.
instead of return the DatePickerDialog like this

> return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (EditSessionActivity)getActivity(), year, month, day);

you should return it in a more generic way

> return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), (OnDateSetListener)getActivity(), year, month, day);

just make sure your activity implements OnDateSetListener interface and override the function onDateSet

```
@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public void onDate(View view) {

        DialogFragment fragment = new SelectDateFragment();
        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");
    }

//  @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    class SelectDateFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            System.out.println("entrering on create dialog");;

            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mYear, mMonth,
                    mDay);//it will return dialog setting date with mYera,MMonth and MDay

        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year,
                int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
            System.out.println("year=" + year + "day=" + dayOfMonth + "month="
                    + monthOfYear);
            mYear=year;
            mMonth=monthOfYear;
            mDay=dayOfMonth;

            onPopulateSet(year, monthOfYear + 1, dayOfMonth);

        }
// set the selected date in the edit text  
        private void onPopulateSet(int year, int i, int dayOfMonth) {
            EditText et_setDate;
            et_setDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_et_dob);//register_et_dob:-id name of the edit text 
            et_setDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/" + i + "/" + year);
            System.out.println("enetring on populate Set");

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

In case you have to return a result to a Fragment, but not an Activity, here is a complete solution:

```
public class DatePickerDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  {

    private static final String ARGUMENT_YEAR = "ARGUMENT_YEAR";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_MONTH = "ARGUMENT_MONTH";
    private static final String ARGUMENT_DAY = "ARGUMENT_DAY";
    private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener;

    private int year;
    private int month;
    private int dayOfMonth;

    public static DatePickerDialogFragment newInstance(final int year, final int month, final int dayOfMonth) {
        final DatePickerDialogFragment df = new DatePickerDialogFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_YEAR, year);
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_MONTH, month);
        args.putInt(ARGUMENT_DAY, dayOfMonth);
        df.setArguments(args);
        return df;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        retrieveArguments();
    }

    private void retrieveArguments() {
        final Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            year = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_YEAR);
            month = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_MONTH);
            dayOfMonth = args.getInt(ARGUMENT_DAY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new DatePickerDialog(getContext(), this.listener, this.year, this.month, this.dayOfMonth);
    }

    public void setListener(final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

Then just use it in a Fragment or in an Activity:

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialogFragment datePicker = DatePickerDialogFragment.newInstance(
        c.get(Calendar.YEAR),
        c.get(Calendar.MONTH),
        c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePicker.setListener(this);
datePicker.show(getChildFragmentManager(), null);
```

Comment: This looks good, except I am getting a problem with `.setListener(this)` when calling in my fragment. I put that code into `onClickListener` for the editText named `bday` where I want to display selected date using `setText`. Any idea how should I do it using ur solution?

Comment: @frank17 if you want to use it inside the click listener and  DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener is implemented by a Fragment, you should do setListener(YourFragment.this).  Otherwise this refers to the clicklistener itself

Answer (score 2):

Leszek's answer works, but not if the Dialog is started from another Fragment. In that case you need to use `setTargetFragment()` in the code that creates the dialog and `getTargetFragment()` in the dialog code.

In the code that creates the dialog:

```
DialogFragment dialogFragment = new YourDialogFragment();
dialogFragment.setTargetFragment(YourParentFragment.this, 0);
dialogFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "mydialog");
```

In the DialogFragment code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
        {
            YourParentFragment parentFragment = (YourParentFragment) getTargetFragment();
            // Manipulate the parent fragment
            // ...
        }
    };
    // Get the initial date
    // ...
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, year, month, day);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem to this, but my date picker was being launched from a dialog fragment inside another fragment. This made it very difficult to play around with the callbacks, because they want to return to the Main Activity and I wanted the data to go back to the previous dialog fragment.

Initially, I passed the new date values to the Main Activity (using the OnDateSetListener) and was going to get them using the dialog that launched the date picker, but there are no lifecycle events triggered in that dialog when the datepicker closes.

The result I came to was in onDismiss in the date picker, instantiate a new dialog fragment, call a set results method on it and then launch it. Of course for this you need to make sure that the previous fragment is dismissed when it launches the date picker.

This is the dialogFragment that called the date picker

```
public class NewTrialDialogFragment extends DialogFragment  {

public final String LOG_TAG = "NewTrialDialog Fragment";

Button startDateButton;
Integer newYear, newMonth, newDay;


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_new_trial, container, false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Dialog New Trial");

    startDateButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_start_date);
    startDateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showDatePickerDialog(v);
        }
    });

    //If you exit the datepicker without choosing anything, it returns zeros
    if (newYear != null && newMonth != null && newDay != null && newYear != 0) {
        startDateButton.setText(newYear + " " + newMonth + " " + newDay);
    }else{
        startDateButton.setText("Select Start Date");
    }

     return rootView;
}

public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    TrialDatePickerDialog newDialog = new TrialDatePickerDialog();
    newDialog.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
    this.dismiss();
}

public void setDates(int year, int month, int day){
    newYear = year;
    newMonth = month;
    newDay = day;
}}
```

And the date picker

```
public  class TrialDatePickerDialog extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener
     {

private final String LOG_TAG = "TrialDatePickerDialog";
int newYear, newMonth, newDay;


@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    // Create a new instance of TrialDatePickerDialog and return it
    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this , year, month, day);
}

         @Override
         public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
             super.onDismiss(dialog);
             FragmentManager fm = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
             NewTrialDialogFragment newTrialDialogFragment = new NewTrialDialogFragment();
             newTrialDialogFragment.setDates(newYear, newMonth, newDay);
             newTrialDialogFragment.show(fm, "new_trial_dialog");

         }

         @Override
         public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
             newYear = year;
             newMonth = monthOfYear;
             newDay = dayOfMonth;
         }
     }
```

Comment: Very creative, but there is an easier way: see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version.

**DatePickerFragment class:**

```
class DatePickerFragment : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {

        val c = Calendar.getInstance()
        val year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)

        return DatePickerDialog(context!!, context!! as MainActivity, year, month, day)
    }
}
```

**DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener** is moved to MainActicity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    ..

    override fun onDateSet(view: DatePicker, year: Int, month: Int, day: Int) {
        //use date in your activity
    }
}
```