# Android returning and displaying DatePicker from DialogFragment class

Tags: android, datepicker, android-dialogfragment

I'm a bit new to Android Programming, so bear with me here...

I'm following the tutorial from [Google Android - Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html), but after following through, I have no idea how to return and display the selected date on the original activity.

If that sounds very confusing now, I currently have 2 classes - *ClassA.java* and *ClassB.java*, where *ClassA* is my main activity, and *ClassB* is my dialog fragment.

I understand that this function below (this is in *ClassB*) takes in the **view, year, month and text** and returns something, but I have no idea how to store it back in the main function in *ClassA* and display it as the currently selected value in the *Spinner* (*TextView*).

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
    // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    return [something];
}
```

My function in *ClassA* uses the code below once the user taps (*onClick*) on the *Spinner* (*TextView*) :

```
public void DatePicker(View v) {
    DialogFragment DateFragment = new NotifyDatePicker();
    DateFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DatePicker");
}
```

So the question is, **where do I start storing the data?** Do I grab the return from *ClassB* to *ClassA* (is there even a returned value?) and store it into a *Bundle* (while also at the same time updating the R.id.TextViewSpinner), or do I save it while the user is inside the *DialogFragment* (*ClassB*)?

**EDIT**

I just realized my mistake. *ClassB* is a separate activity on its own, so changing of the *Spinner* (*TextView*) and storing of the Bundle should be done in *ClassB*...

There's one small problem though.

I'm using *(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner).setText(daymonthyear)* but an error keeps coming up :

```
The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ClassB
```

Is there something I've forgotten to **import/include**?

**FULL CODES**

```
public class ClassB extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

@Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

        // Change TextViewSpinner here (setText)

        // Tried (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner).setText(daymonthyear) - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ClassB error returned

        // Tried (TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner) - context cannot be resolved error returned

        return;
    }
}
```

This is via the [Google Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html). I've been tweaking here and there but it always throws me back to square one...

Comment: nope, doesn't work. hold on, i'll include my codes...

Comment: thanks. i'm still trying to solve this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe not the best solution, but you can use the `DefaultSharedPreferences` to save the values:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    preferences.putInt("year", year);
    preferences.putInt("month", month);
    preferences.putInt("day", day;
    preferences.commit();

    return;
}
```

and do something with them in Activity A:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
int year = preferences.getInt("year", 0);
int month = preferences.getInt("month", 0);
int day = preferences.getInt("day", 0);

(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner).setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
```

I hope this helps.

It is by the way recommended to have references like `TextViewSpinner` start with a non-capital letter: `textViewSpinner`.

Comment: what about updating the text in TextViewSpinner? How would I go about doing it? Was debugging a bit yesterday, but no dice... Would (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner) normally work?

Comment: Right, solved it - looks like you need to callback to the original activity for handling -- you cant just ask a DialogFragment to handle Activity stuff

Answer (score 1):

There is actually no need to take the detour via the shared preferences. All you have to do is tell your `ClassB` where to look for the view:

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    // Change TextViewSpinner here (setText)

    // Tried (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner).setText(daymonthyear)
    // - The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type ClassB error returned

    // Instead try:
    (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner)
        .setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year)

    // Tried (TextView)context.findViewById(R.id.TextViewSpinner)
    // - context cannot be resolved error returned

    return;
}
```

For the full code of the class extending `DialogFragment` (in your case `ClassB`) see [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16502599/461544) to a similar question.