# Date picker dialog is not working in fragment

Tags: java, android, date, android-datepicker

**here i  have made a simple code for date picker which works for current date, year and day,it is not working for fragment**

```
   public class Activity extends Sherlockfragment {

    EditText  dob;
    public static final int DATE_DIALOG_ID = 1009;
    String dob_string;
    int year = 2013, month = 10, day = 1, dayofmonth = 1;

@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_profile, container, false);

            mdob = (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.dob);
          mdob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            showDialog(DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }});
return view;
}

// ****************************#DATE PICKER DIALOG# **************************
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DATE_DIALOG_ID:
        // set date picker as current date
        return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener, year, month,
                day);
    }
    return null;
}

 private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener = new   DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
            int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth + 1;
        day = selectedDay;
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
        DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
        String weekdays[] = dfs.getWeekdays();
        int daykk = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        String dayof = weekdays[daykk];
        mdob.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" + year + dayof);
        mdob_string = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;
    }};
    }
```

Comment: Exactly what happen? And What do you exactly want?

Comment: Do you have a question to ask ?

Comment: Not working means what..

Comment: public final boolean showDialog (int id, Bundle args) **Added in API level 8 This method was deprecated in API level 13**. Use the new **DialogFragment** class with FragmentManager instead; this is also available on older platforms through the **Android compatibility package**.

Comment: @PiyushGupta it is not working so can you provide me any reference

Comment: @Michel http://www.kylebeal.com/2011/11/android-datepickerdialog-and-the-dialogfragment/ check this one

Comment: I just found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527051/get-date-from-datepicker-using-dialogfragment, this will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a custom class for that as below:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

Reference: [Pickers with Fragment](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
public class Activity extends Sherlockfragment {

    static EditText  mdob;

    static String dob_string;


@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update_profile, container, false);

            mdob = (EditText)view. findViewById(R.id.dob);
          mdob.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();

                        newFragment.show(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");

        }});
return view;
}
    // *********************************CLASS****************************************************************************



public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
            DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        int year = 2013, month = 10, day = 1, dayofmonth = 1;


        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
            // Do something with the date chosen by the user

            year = selectedYear;
            month = selectedMonth + 1;
            day = selectedDay;
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
            DateFormatSymbols dfs = new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.getDefault());
            String weekdays[] = dfs.getWeekdays();
            int daykk = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            String dayof = weekdays[daykk];

 Activity.mdob.setText(day + "-" + month + "-" +        year + dayof);
 Activity.mdob_string = day + "-" + month + "-" + year;

        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: it is working properly....