# How can I get time and date which is selected by user in TimePicker and DatePicker?

Tags: android, datepicker, dialog, timepicker

```
package com.example.timepickerdialog;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.TimePickerDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.TimePicker;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
        // Get Current Date or use your own Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        final int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        final int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        DatePickerDialog saadadatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        //get date here
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mYear+"/"+mDay+"/"+mMonth, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        saadadatePickerDialog.show();

    }

    public void showTimePickerDialog(View v) {
        // Get Current Time or use your own Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        final int mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        final int mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog saadatimePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
```

I want to print that time and date in toast which is selected by user. But in this code  only current Date and Time show.

```
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, mHour+":"+mMinute, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }, mHour, mMinute, false);
            saadatimePickerDialog.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32711590/7498057

Comment: Can you plz explain, I don't understand?

Answer (score 1):

Please set below code for datepicker dialog.

```
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                    new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                              int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

Toast.makeText(mActivity,dayOfMonth + "-" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
            datePickerDialog.show();
```

For Timepicker dialog

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {

                        Toast.makeText(mActivity, hourOfDay + ":" + minute, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        timePickerDialog.show();
```

Hope it may help you.