# Trying to pass data back from DialogFragment to parent Acitivity

Tags: android

In my usecase, i am showing a TextView which when clicked pops up a Calendar. When the date is selected the calender view is closed and the TextView is populated with the selected date.

After a few experiments - i used a `DialogFragment` which pops up and closes as the date is selected. So far it is looking good.

The challenge is that i need to update the TextView in the parent activity with the date selected.
Based on my knowledge using `LocalBroadcastManager` is one of the method, but is there something simpler?  e.g. Activity getting the value directly from the DialogFragment or something on lines of startActivityWithResult?

Please suggest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905312/receive-result-from-dialogfragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get date from datepicker using dialogfragment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11527051/get-date-from-datepicker-using-dialogfragment)

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces are very useful here

> The easiest way to communicate between your activity and fragments is
>   using interfaces. The idea is basically to define an interface inside
>   a given fragment A and let the activity implement that interface.
>
> Once it has implemented that interface, you could do anything you want
>   in the method it overrides.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25392549/5993410)